# What is being said in this short audio clip, translated as "If you vacuum on high, it can't suck dust as much"?

Tags: translation

[Here](https://instaud.io/2C1H) is the audio.

Some frame: there is a mom who explained his child how to vacuum, and explained him that using the vacuum cleaner at high power wouldn't help to suck all the dust. He repeats this concept at a school (first grade) show.

I have this translation: "If you vacuum on high, it can't suck dust as much".
I can't get what does "on high" means, so I'd be really grateful to you if you could help me getting a proper translation.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

청소기는 너무 세게 틀면 안된다. 먼지가 더 안 들어온다.
"If you use vacuum with too much power,  it can't suck dust as much"
I don't think it makes much sense, but apparently mom thinks that she needs to set the vacuum power level to medium instead of the highest..